# Is there a definitive formula for this combination?

Tags: combinatorics

To help Lavanya learn all about binary numbers and binary sequences, her father has bought her a collection of square tiles, each of which has either a 0 or a 1 written on it. Her brother Nikhil has played a rather nasty prank. He has glued together pairs of tiles with 0 written on them. Lavanya now has square tiles with 1 on them and rectangular tiles with two 0's on them, made up of two square tiles with 0 stuck together). Thus, she can no longer make all possible binary sequences using these tiles.
To amuse herself, Lavanya has decided to pick a number N and try and construct as many binary sequences of length N as possible using her collection of tiles. For example if N = 1, she can only make the sequence 1. For N=2, she can make 11 and 00. For N=4, there are 5 possiblities: 0011, 0000, 1001, 1100 and 1111

Ok practically you would count as this: set no of 0 pairs and then find how many locations are available for them.

For example N=7. let no of 0 pairs be denoted by k. when k=0 there is one possibillity 1111111. when k=1 there is 7-1=6 possibilities for the pair and rest go to 1s like 0011111,1001111,1100111 and so on and so on.

I want to ask can this be converted into a definite formula?

Comment: Have you tried creating a recurrence relation and solving it?

Comment: @TravisJ why didn't I thought of that. maybe the problem's solved.

Comment: @TravisJ recurrence relation is not formable, there' some key problem.

Comment: I tried to write out how to do it below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t_{n}$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ she can create.  Look at the last entry, if it is a 1, then she obtained the sequence by building a sequence of length $n-1$ and tacked on a 1.  Otherwise, if it was a 0 (the last digit) then she tacked a $00$ onto a string of length $n-2$.  So the number is $t_{n}=t_{n-1}+t_{n-2}$ which looks a lot like the Fibonnaci sequence.  You just have different initial conditions.

Comment: If you haven't solved recurrence relations before, check out this source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#General_methods the example is very close to the relation here.

Comment: oh you worked the recurrence backwards of the way i was going, i was going from $t_{n-1},t_{n-2},..$ to $t_n$

Comment: @ADG, it's tricky if you go that direction, because you do some overcounting...